# How to do df only on root partition?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, df

How can get df results only for `/` partition. The partition name/identification (`/dev/sda2`, `/dev/cciss/c0d0p1`) could vary on different computers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can specify a directory or file on command line and the file system that contains that file/directory.

```
$ df /
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       63579860 22097564  38297452  37% /
```

You can read more on the manpage, `df(1)`.

Comment: I was searching for string "root" on the manpage...

Comment: What's the point of using directory name with df? If we exclude my original question, what could be another reason to use directory or even file name with df?

Comment: Using df with a directory (or filename) is handy if you want to know how much data (approximately) you can store into specific directory without being interested what block device it belongs to. Imagine you have e.g. some media library mounted over NFS: then you can just 'df /mnt/media_lib'.